# RSA uses substitution and shuffling?

Tags: rsa

I've been doing some searches for RSA and it appears that it uses shuffling but not substitution. Is this true?

Simple explanation of the algorithm:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rsa-algorithm-cryptography/

Answer (score 2):

> I've been doing some searches for RSA and it appears that it uses shuffling but not substitution.

RSA is a mathematical algorithm. Neither of these terms is applicable to it.

Generally speaking, the terms "shuffling" and "substitution" are generally only applicable to extremely simple, pre-electronic cryptographic techniques -- Vigenère ciphers, columnar transpositions, and the like. They are not especially relevant to modern encryption.